# how to filter and display the table view and collection view values based on the bool value in my json

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, filter

I have the json list of :

```
 [
     {

         "title": "Languages",
         "name_list": [
             {

                 "title": "Hindi",
                 "locked": true
             },
             {
                 "title": "Hindi1",
                 "locked": true
             },
             {
                 "title": "Hindi2",
                 "locked": false
             },
             {
                 "title": "Hindi3",
                 "locked": true
             },
             {
                 "title": "Hindi4",
                 "locked": false
             }],
     },
     {

         "title": "Subject",
         "name_list": [
             {
                 "title": "Hindi4",
                 "locked": false
             },
             {
                 "title": "Hindi4",
                 "locked": true
             },
             {
                 "title": "Hindi4",
                 "locked": true
             }]
     }    
 ]
```

I am using table view and inside table view i have collection view.

Now in my table view i will show the title .And in my collection view i will show the `name_list` title on each collection view cell. Now it's working fine.

What i needs is, as you can see in the json, that have many locked =  true and false.

So,  In my table view- which object have less `locked == false`. that title i needs to show as first. For example.

In my above json, title = subject have only one locked = false, but title = language have 2 locked = false. So in my table view first subject have to display and language.

Same in each collection view, which object have locked = false that needs to display first in my collection view cell.

Any help please.

Here is my code of table view :

`cellTitleLabel.text = jsonData?["title"] as? String ?? ""`

in my collection view :

```
if let gamesList = jsonData?["name_list"]  as? [[String: Any]] {
   let Info = nameList[indexPath.item]
   collectionCell.cellTitleLabel.text = Info["title"] as? String ?? ""
}

   var Info: [String: Any]?{
        didSet {

            cellTitleLabel.text = jsonData?["title"] as? String ?? ""
            collectionView.reloadData();

            guard let gamesList = jsonData?["name_list"]  as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using custom structs to parse your data? The handling would be much easier i think.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. So you want to order your table view so that those with least locked are on top. And you want to order cells in each of your collection view so that locked are first and then unlocked?

Comment: @MaticOblak yes exactly. But u tried through code with asc, dec, but it dosent wokr.

Comment: Some code about how you use your data source would be nice so we can continue building from that or to fix it. But let me see what I can do...

Comment: @MaticOblak i updated Please check and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

I used this below json for dummy

```
[
    {
        "title": "Languages",
        "name_list": [
            {
                "title": "Sub 1",
                "locked": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub 2",
                "locked": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub 3",
                "locked": false
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub 4",
                "locked": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub 5",
                "locked": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Subject",
        "name_list": [
            {
                "title": "Sub 6",
                "locked": false
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub 7",
                "locked": false
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub 8",
                "locked": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Model Struct for this json :

```
public struct TestModel {

    public var nameList : [NameList]
    public var title : String
}

public struct NameList {

    public var locked : Bool
    public var title : String

}
```

My json is in local project, so I use this below func to

```
func getLocalData(){
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "testjson", withExtension: "json")!
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [Any]
       self.arrData = self.createDataModel(json)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Func to bind the json into model struct

```
func createDataModel (_ json : [Any]) -> [TestModel] {
    var arr = [TestModel]()

    for adata in json {
        let aDictItems = adata as! [String : Any]
        let aNameListData = aDictItems["name_list"] as! [Any]
        var arrNameList = [NameList]()

        for aName in aNameListData {
            let adictname = aName as! [String : Any]
            arrNameList.append(NameList.init(locked: adictname["locked"] as! Bool, title: adictname["title"] as! String ))
        }

        arr.append(TestModel.init(nameList: arrNameList, title: aDictItems["title"] as! String))

    }
    return arr
}
```

And in last, func that sort your list into the number of locked count (`false`) and return back filtered data.

```
func filterData (_ searchText : String) -> [TestModel] {
    if searchText == "" { return arrData }

    let s = arrData.sorted { (res1, res2) -> Bool in
        var count1 = 0, count2 = 0
        for r in res1.nameList {
            if !r.locked {
                count1 += 1
            }
        }
        for r in res2.nameList {
            if !r.locked {
                count2 += 1
            }
        }
        return count1 > count2
    }

    let f = s.filter {
        $0.nameList.contains(where: { (aNameRes) -> Bool in
          aNameRes.title.contains(searchText)
        })
    }
    return f
}
```

---

> Edit : To Show data in cell

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return filtered.Count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    :
    // filtered[indexPath.row].title // your tableview cell title
    // filtered[indexPath.item].nameList // your collectView Data, Use this array to show data in collectionview
}
```

**Note:** Your API json Data and filtered data is always be same. When there is no string in the search bar then you need to toggle filtered data with api original data.

---

If something change in your requirement then let me know.

Comment: how can i append to my table view and collection view label text in this case ?

Comment: collection view label text ?? didint got you.

Comment: i have to display the title in my table view, as well as having collection view which have label to show to name. How can so that from where

Comment: for table view : i do `cellTitleLabel.text = jsonData?["title"] as? String ?? ""` but here from where i can get the data to display ?

Comment: If u have done this demo with both table view and colelction with populate the data. Please send me, That would be helpful

Comment: Can you show me how your tableview and collectionview looked like so that I will change accordingly.

Comment: i attched an image

Comment: Jesus have you ever tried coding without declaring all you properties as implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Comment: @LeoDabus What do you mean?

Comment: `public struct NameList {` 

    `public let locked: Bool`
    `public let title: String`

`}`

Comment: @david Func little more changed after leo comments, I have directly unwraped the data in create func or you can use in this way too for more safe -> `TestModel.init(nameList: arrNameList, title: aDictItems["title"] as? String ?? "")`

Comment: @LeoDabus Pls check now.

Comment: @dahiya_boy can u please send me the demo project if u doe any for this

Comment: @david I pasted all the code.If you need further any help you can ask.

Comment: arrData is an simaple array ?? like ` let arrData = [Any]`

Comment: @david No its `var arrData : [TestModel] = []` and give me your demo with tableview & collectionView setup, I will add the answer.

Comment: @dahiya_boy actually its one module, not able to send as full project. So only asked for demo from ur end. or else can i send u the two files to ur email id ?

Comment: @david Your whole answer is updated in this post. You just need to copy paste now.

Comment: @david Add `if searchText == "" { return arrData }` in filterData Func (answer updated). Use filterArray. After getting the data do `filterData = arrData` and `tblView.reloadData()` . You need both arrData and filterArray. But for to show data use filterArray

Comment: @david here are two file complete [1](https://gist.github.com/thedahiyaboy/aa98265eda83eb5280deffdbc9109ed4) and [2](https://gist.github.com/thedahiyaboy/2dcbccc11d82761c530b87b72438b3db).

Comment: @dahiya_boy ia m not using any search here. i  needs to display from my json list initially. Please have a look of my two class. U get to know https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97QeJKOjA1LOTR1c09jSU84NkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @David check my most and filtering method

Answer (score 0):

My solution here is to create a function in your tableview cell and call it at cellForRowAt indexPath with the corresponding array. And you can call the function simply by `cell. fillCollectionView(array)`.

```
class ExampleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var exampleCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var array = [[String:Any]]()

func fillCollectionView(with array: [[String:Any]]) {
    self.array = array
    exampleCollectionView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, If you want to display `locked == false` as first then you need to rearrange your dictionary of array(sort by locked). and then load data into `UItableview` and `UIcollectionview`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function and it will work for you without creating any models.

```
func sortArr(array : [[String:Any]]) -> [[String:Any]]{
var arr = array
for i in 0...arr.count - 1 {
    var dict = arr[i]
    let name_list = dict["name_list"] as! [[String:Any]]
    let lockedItems = name_list.filter { (item) -> Bool in
        let locked = item["locked"] as! Bool
        if locked == false {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    print(lockedItems.count)
    dict["lockedItems"] = lockedItems.count
    arr[i] = dict
}
arr = arr.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    let lockedcount1 = item1["lockedItems"] as! Int
    let lockedcount2 = item2["lockedItems"] as! Int
    return lockedcount1 < lockedcount2
})
return arr
}
```

**EDITED**

```
import UIKit
var arr = [
[

"title": "Languages",
"name_list": [
[
"title": "Hindi",
"locked": true
],
[
"title": "Hindi1",
"locked": true
],
[
"title": "Hindi2",
"locked": false
],
[
"title": "Hindi3",
"locked": true
],
[
"title": "Hindi4",
"locked": false
]],
],
```

[

```
"title": "Subject",
"name_list": [
[
"title": "Hindi4",
"locked": false
],
[
"title": "Hindi4",
"locked": true
],
[
"title": "Hindi4",
"locked": true
]]
]
```

]

```
func sortArr(array : [[String:Any]]) -> [[String:Any]]{
    var arr = array
    for i in 0...arr.count - 1 {
        var dict = arr[i]
        let name_list = dict["name_list"] as! [[String:Any]]
        let lockedItems = name_list.filter { (item) -> Bool in
            let locked = item["locked"] as! Bool
            if locked == false {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        print(lockedItems.count)
        dict["lockedItems"] = lockedItems.count
        arr[i] = dict
    }
    arr = arr.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
        let lockedcount1 = item1["lockedItems"] as! Int
        let lockedcount2 = item2["lockedItems"] as! Int
        return lockedcount1 < lockedcount2
    })
    return arr
}

var array = sortArr(array: arr)
print(array)
```

Comment: can u please add bit code wr, i needs to pass the `[[String:Any]]` and again to show in my label text

Comment: u used only lockedcount1, lockedcount2 but in my josn i can get many object like that.Not fixed 2

Comment: mate , this is a loop, it runs on each element of an array. This is a sorting function provided by swift. Try it with multiple items in your array , it will work just fine

Comment: I am bit confused. I posted my structure in my question. please help with some code example

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Root {
    let nameList: [NameList]
    let title : String
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
        self.nameList = (dictionary["name_list"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []).map(NameList.init)
    }
}
```

---

```
struct NameList {
    let locked: Bool
    let title: String
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.locked =  dictionary["locked"] as? Bool == true
        self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let jsonData = Data("""
[
  {
    "title" : "Languages",
    "name_list" : [
      {
        "title" : "Hindi",
        "locked" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Hindi1",
        "locked" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Hindi2",
        "locked" : false
      },
      {
        "title" : "Hindi3",
        "locked" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Hindi4",
        "locked" : false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title" : "Subject",
    "name_list" : [
      {
        "title" : "Hindi4",
        "locked" : false
      },
      {
        "title" : "Hindi4",
        "locked" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Hindi4",
        "locked" : true
      }
    ]
  }
]
""".utf8)

let dictionaries = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)) as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
```

---

```
print("\nAll Models", terminator: "\n============\n")
let models = dictionaries.map(Root.init)
for model in models {
    print(model.title)
    for name in model.nameList {
        print(name.title)
     }
}
print("\nunlockedModels", terminator: "\n============\n")
let unlockedDictionary: [String: [NameList]] = models.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1.title] = $1.nameList.filter{ $0.locked}
}
for (title, nameList) in unlockedDictionary {
    print(title)
    for name in nameList {
        print(name.title)
    }
}
```